Route values are lost in the second pass of OnInitializedAsync() in Blazor Server
Problem:
In Blazor Server with render mode 'ServerPrerendered', I am observing that the route values are present in the first call of OnInitializedAsync().

However, the route values become empty after the framework calls OnInitializedAsync() the second time.
Question

Is there a way to get the route values after the second call? I tried the 'Server' render mode rather than 'ServerPrerendered'. It resulted in calling the OnInitializedAsync() only once, but route values are empty.

My goal is to enable route based localization by getting language name from route (e.g. '//mypage'. As the routes are lost after the 2nd call, the language code cannot be obtained and the page fails to be localized.
Test Project in GitHub
https://github.com/tsutomua/blazor/tree/main/BlazorLocalizationTest

As you are using Net8 - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerender?view=aspnetcore-8.0#persist-prerendered-state

Can you use NavigationManager to get the URI?

Thanks @MrCakaShaunCurtis. I was able to get the route values at the second call.  I am trying to find out how the recovered value (the language tag) can be used to display the localized page. No luck so far, but this is a different issue.

Thanks @DavidThielen, I do see the full URI at the 2nd call with the NavigationManager!

Thanks @MrCakaShaunCurtis & @DavidThielen. Both solutions, use 1) PersistingComponentStateSubscription or 2) use MavigationManager) worked.
